# Process string-valued columns from a CSV file with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas to process my CSV file for machine learning.

The CSV file contains a columns of tags, written in English, such as "math" and "literature". I want to map those tags to integers like "math":1, "literature":2. How can I do this with Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can feed a `dict` with the strings as keys ('math', etc) and the integers as values into the `map` method. For example:

```
>>> df

   x     subject
0  1        math
1  2  literature
2  3        math
3  4        math
4  5     science

>>> df['num'] = df.subject.map({'math':0,'literature':1,'science':2})
>>> df

   x     subject  num
0  1        math    0
1  2  literature    1
2  3        math    0
3  4        math    0
4  5     science    2
```

You could also use `factorize` to accomplish much the same thing but you wouldn't control the mapping from string to integers (although in this example it ends up being the same):

```
>>> df['num'] = pd.factorize(df.subject)[0]
>>> df

   x     subject  num
0  1        math    0
1  2  literature    1
2  3        math    0
3  4        math    0
4  5     science    2
```